# Rails API + MongoDB passing parameters to the url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, api, jbuilder

i have simple API example with simple GET routing.
I have MongoDB and my document from collection look's like this:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("51411cf11b4cb1b19a7115c0"),
"name" : "some_name",
"type" : "some_type",
"services" : [ 
    "service_one", 
    "service_two"
],
"location" : {
    "type" : "some_type",
    "description" : "Some  description",
},
"address" : {
    "street" : "some_street",
    "building" : "building",
    "post_code" : "some_post_code",
    "city" : "some_city",
    "province" : "some_province"
  }
}
```

My controller:

```
class V1::DataController < V1::ApplicationController

  def index
    @data = Data.all
    render 'v1/data/index'
  end

  def show
    @data = Data.find_by(name: params[:id])
    render json: @data
  end
end
```

I use **jbuilder** to render my output.
Now, my question is, how to make that parameter passed in the url, was reflected in the json result ? For example, my Mongo document have "name", so i wanna sort result by name.

http://api.loc:3000/data?name=some_name

Can you write a simple example?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Mongoid?

Comment: Yes, i'm using Mongoid

Answer (score 0):

Some of the naming conventions used in your example are a little weird. If all you want to do is sort I would consider changing the "name" parameter to something more descriptive. Keeping with your example the following might help.

```
class V1::DataController < V1::ApplicationController
  ...
  def index
    #ASC
    if data_params[:order].eql?('asc')
      @data = Data.asc(data_params[:name])
    else
      #DESC
      @data = Data.desc(data_params[:name])
    end
    render 'v1/data/index'
  end

  def data_params
    params.permit(:name, :order)
  end
end
```

Comment: I'v done it in another way:

`def index
sort_it = params[:order] || 'desc'
order_by = params[:order_by] || 'something'
@points = Point.all.order(order_by => sort_it)
render 'v1/data/index'
end`